# TERADATA: SQL recursive query that selects from a recursive query

Tags: sql, teradata, recursive-query

I am trying to perform recursion multiple times using Teradata
my query is similar to the following, upon referencing the query_1 from query_2 and trying to run it gives an error saying that query_1 doesn't exist.

> ```
> WITH 
> RECURSIVE query_1
> AS (
>  --some recursive query
> )
>    ,RECURSIVE query_2
>    AS (
>    --another recursive query based on results from query_1
>    )
> SELECT *
> FROM query_2
> ```

I want to concatenate values from different levels of hierarchy
so I want to turn

```
------------------------------------
 trx    indx1   indx2   val
------------------------------------
 x1      1       1       a
 x1      1       2       b
 x1      1       3       c
 x1      2       1       d
...................................
-----------------------------------
```

Into the following

```
----------------
 trx        val
----------------
 x1       a/b/c/d
```

Comment: You can't have nested recursive queries (and I can't imagine why you should need it).

Comment: I want to concatenate from multiple levels of hierarchy

Comment: Not sure about Terada, but with standard SQL, the `recursive` keyword must only be specified **once** right after the `WITH` keyword, regardless which of the CTEs is recursive. Did you try to remove the second `RECURSIVE` keyword?

Comment: You can use XMLAGG to concatenate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29549409/2527905 or you concatenated while you do the hierarchy query.

Comment: XMLAGG  has done it for me!
however the ORDER BY supports only one column so I had to concatenate every level in a subquery

Answer (score 0):

XMLAGG function solved the problem

```
    SELECT TRX
        , TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM (XMLAGG(TRIM(val)|| '/' ORDER BY indx1||indx2 ASC) (VARCHAR(10000)))) val
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY 1,2
```

however, I wish the "order by" inside XMLAGG supports multiple expressions this way we won't need subqueries to concatenate multiple levels of hierarchies.

thanks [donoeth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2527905/dnoeth) for the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510654/listagg-equivalent-in-teradata/29549409#29549409)

Comment: There's no need for two aggregations, simply combine both columns into one, e.g. `SELECT TRX
        , Trim(Trailing '/' FROM (XmlAgg(Trim(val)|| '/' ORDER BY indx1||indx2 ASC) (VARCHAR(10000)))) val
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY 1`

Comment: @dnoeth XMLAGG fails when it finds non english characters, is there any work around?

Comment: It's probably not failing due to XMLAGG but due to a wrong session character set, should be UTF-8 or UTF16.