# how to convert xmlget and xmlelement from teradata to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata, teradatasql

Below is the teradata code i want to convert to snowflake

```
    select XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (n, col1
    || CHR (10))
   ORDER BY num
  ).EXTRACT ('//text()').getClobVal () AS abc
```

tried as below but not working. am new to both oracle and snowflake please help me with this

```
extract(listagg (parse_xml('<n> col1||  CHR (10) <n>')),'//text()')
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant snippet(s) of the XML document and the intended output?

Comment: @GregPavlik, Im not quite sure. i just want alternative for xmlagg,xmlelement and getclobval in snowflake

Comment: There are a few XML functions, parse_xml will convert a string to a variant in XML. What you probably will need to use is xmlget: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/xmlget.html 

This shows how to use it on hierarchical XML: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/HOW-TO-QUERY-NESTED-XML-DATA-IN-SNOWFLAKE

Comment: @Kyle instead of sharing the Teradata code, it would be better to share a sample XML and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly your Teradata code is simply a polyfill (aka a work around) for the historic [lack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510654/listagg-equivalent-in-teradata) of `LISTAGG`  in Teradata.

Likely you simply need this code

```
SELECT
  LISTAGG(col1,'\n') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY num)
```

Comment: If you have a lot of this kind of code to migrate, it is worth considering using tooling to help automate SQL code conversions https://medium.com/@paulgvernon/why-is-sql-so-incompatible-edae60831a3

Comment: LISTAGG( to_xml(object_construct('',load_name )) ,'\n') this is providing the output but extract and getclobval is not applied. any idea on how to get that functionality in snowflake @paulvernon

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need whatever extract and getclobval are doing because they are all part of the polyfill in Teradata - they are all replaced by the simple LISTAGG in Snowflake.